# MySQL Clarification

Tags: mysql

So Im starting to learn MySQL, and I was a bit confused about tables, so I wanted to clarify this. Can there be multiple tables in a database? For example:

```
Database1
-Table1
 -Username
 -Password
-Table2
 -Name
 -Dogname
```

Thanks.

Edit:

```
$username = "root"; 
$password = "pass123"; 
$db = "login"; 
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", $username, $password); 
$conndb = mysql_select_db($db); 
$ask = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users", $conn); 
echo $ask; 
mysql_close();
```

Edit2:
Kinda off topic from the original question, but why isn't this code working?

```
<?php
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "pass123";
$db = "login";
$conn = @mysql_connect("localhost:3306", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($db);

$userid = $_POST["userid"];
$userpass = $_POST["userpass"];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = {$userid}");
echo $sql;

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 1){
    //user not found
    echo "Found user login!";
} else {
    //user found
    echo "Could not find user";

}

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

And it keeps giving me the error "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\login.php on line 19". Why is this being caused?

Comment: Not exclusively a mysql question - you should maybe research databases (avoiding data warehouses for now)

Comment: Sorry, the websites that I found were a bit complicated (Yes I know I'm dumb)

Comment: Thereis some useful stuff (and some rubbish) on youtube (search for database) some introductory tutorials for sql  -http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp and you could sign up for microsoft virtual acadamy (it's free) - I know you are interested in mysql but some of the courses are concept rather than product based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there can be multiple tables.

Take the example of a book.

Suppose book is your database.
And there are pages which are your tables.
And in the pages there is horizontal and vertical lines which divides the table into rows and columns.

Inside the pages, for particular column you can add data accordingly. And book can have multiple pages. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Helped alot

Comment: @LachlanMather Glad to help. Always connect with real life objects and it will give you a complete different view of the concept and makes it easy to understand :)

Comment: Just quickly I've got another question, so Im using MySQL and I keep seeing MySQLi everywhere in examples. I know this stands for 'Improved', but alot of the code like mysql_connect(); is deprecated nowdays, so should I switch to MySQLi (I have a WAMP server so Im not sure how to install MySQLi)? And my current code for trying to get all data from table 'users' is the edited bit at the top. And it keeps echo'ing "Resource id #4", what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: @LachlanMather First thing first. `Mysql` is the database and there are api to connect to it. Earlier `mysql_*` based functions were used but they are deprecated and you should use `mysqli` or `PDO`. I would suggest `PDO`. Can you please post the exact error you are getting in the question?

Comment: @LachlanMather After the query you do need to fetch the data. `$b  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ask)` and then `print_r($b);`

Comment: That is literally all im getting other than a deprecated warning. Here's a picture: http://imgur.com/a/ruRKr

Comment: You can remove the warning by adding `@`before `mysql_connect()`

Comment: Ok thanks, found a few examples that helped me as well. Much *apprecated* ;)

Comment: @LachlanMather Glad to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125982/discussion-between-lachlan-mather-and-kinshuk-lahiri).

Comment: @LachlanMather Replied to your query in chat. You can ask further things there.

Answer (score 0):

In a word - yes. I'd say that not only can there be more than one table in a database, for any real-world usecase, there usually are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible for a MySQL database to have multiple tables. Think the database as a library and the tables as sections of the library. There may be different types of libraries such as a medical library. And in a medical library you may have dozens of sections about medical studies. The books are your database entries and have properties such as title, page count etc.

Hope this answer helps you understanding the basic concepts, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can create unlimited tables on MySQL. The only problem you may run into is not having enough disk space on your server making processes slow, slowing down your site. I would recommend you get a dedicated server with 2x500GB hard drive and host MySQL by itself on one of the drives so you can process your files and DB from separate partitions. That's what I did for my two website dashikidresses.com and ratchetqueens.com and they're super fast.

Comment: Im not hosting a public website yet, Im just messing around with localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Of course **YES**.

One server can have many databases, One database can have many [tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(database)) or [views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)), One table can have many columns and rows.

Besides you might come across terminologies like [indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index), procedures, [triggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger), [primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key), [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in your exciting journey. Good luck.